# Obtaining martingales from Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

All processes here are continuous. Suppose we have a Poisson process $(N_t)_{t\geq 0}$ with parameter $\lambda > 0$ and adapted to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$. Fix $u\in\mathbb{C}$, let $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and define the process 
$$X_t = e^{iuN_t - \lambda t(e^{iu}-1)}.$$

From this, I want to show that $(Re(X_t))_{t\geq 0}$ and $(Im(X_t))_{t\geq 0}$ are $\mathcal{F}_t$-martingales.

**Here is what I have done so far:** We can assume $u\neq 0$. The first thing I did was write $$X_t = \frac{e^{iuN_t}}{E[e^{iuY}]},$$
where $Y$ is any Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda t$. Now we have that
$$X_t = \frac{e^{iuN_t}}{E[e^{iuY}]} = $$
$$ = \frac{\cos(uN_t)E[\cos(uY)] + \sin(uN_t)E[\sin(uY)] + i\big(\sin(uN_t)E[\cos(uY)] + \cos(uN_t)E[\sin(uY)]\big)}{E[\sin(uY)]^2 + E[\cos(uY)]^2}.$$

Therefore 
$$E[Re(X_t)]=\frac{E[\cos(uN_t)]E[\cos(uY)] + E[\sin(uN_t)]E[\sin(uY)]}{E[\sin(uY)]^2 + E[\cos(uY)]^2} < \infty$$
for the numerator is finite and the denominator is positive. The same reasoning applies to the imaginary part of $X_t$.

The hard part is to show that $E[Re(X_t)|\mathcal{F}_s] = Re(X_s)$ for all $t>s$. I need a help here.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Can you prove that $E(X_t\mid\mathcal F_s)=X_s$?

Comment: I had some problems trying to compute $E[Re(X_t)\cdot\textbf{I}_A]$, for $A\in\mathcal{F}_s$. This always leads me to horrible computations with sines and cosines. I just tried this for  $E[X_t\cdot\textbf{I}_A]$ and got the same problems.

Comment: No, the computations with X are much simpler than with Re(X) and Im(X).

Comment: For any $A\in\mathcal{F}_s$, $E[X_t\cdot\textbf{I}_A] =$ $e^{-\lambda t(e^{iu}-1)}E[e^{iuN_t}\cdot\textbf{I}_A] =$ $e^{-\lambda t(e^{iu}-1)}E[(\cos(uN_t)+i\sin(uN_t))\cdot\textbf{I}_A] =$ $e^{-\lambda t(e^{iu}-1)}\big( E[\cos(uN_t)\cdot\textbf{I}_A]+iE[\sin(uN_t)\cdot\textbf{I}_A] \big)$. This is what I got, maybe there is some shortcut I'm missing.

Comment: Again? Just stay with the complex exponential instead of complicating things with the sine and cosine.

Comment: Ok. I think I'm in the right track now! For any $A\in\mathcal{F}_s$, we have $E[X_t\cdot\textbf{I}_A] = e^{-\lambda t(e^{iu}-1)}E[e^{iuN_t}\cdot\textbf{I}_A]$. Write $A=\{a_j: j\in J\}$ for some countable index set $J$. Then $E[e^{iuN_t}\cdot\textbf{I}_A]$ = $\sum_{j\in J}e^{iux_j}\cdot P[e^{iuN_t} = e^{uix_j}] = $ $\sum_{j\in J}e^{iux_j}\cdot P[N_t = x_j] = $ $\sum_{j\in J}e^{iux_j}\cdot\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x_j}}{x_j!}$, where $x_j = N_t(a_j)$.

Comment: Doing the same computations for $E[X_s\cdot\textbf{I}_A]$ we get $\sum_{j\in J}e^{iuy_j}\cdot\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{y_j}}{y_j!}$, where $y_j = N_s(a_j)$. For some reason this two expectations must be equal, I just don't know why.

Comment: Looks still somewhat overcomplicated. Can you calculate $$\mathbb{E}(e^{i u (N_t-N_s)} \mid \mathcal{F}_s)$$ for $s \leq t$? Use that $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has independent stationary increments. (And what exactly do you mean by "all processes here are continuous"? Have you ever seen a continuous Poisson process?)

Comment: This is the problem 3.3.21 from Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus - Karatzas, Shreve. The Poisson process they are considering are continuous ( by *continuous* I mean the parameter set are not discrete, it's $[0,\infty)$ in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I know how to solve this problem. Thank you Did and saz for the help (let me know if there is anything wrong with my solution, I'll try to fix as soon as I can).

First of all, the Poisson process $(N_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is such that $N_0=0$ a.s., and $E[N_t-N_s] = \lambda (t-s)$ for $s<t$. In particular, $E[N_t-N_0] = E[N_t] = \lambda t$ for any $t > 0$. Therefore,
$$X_t = e^{iuN_t - \lambda t(e^{iu}-1)} = \frac{e^{iuN_t}}{E[e^{iuN_t}]}.$$

From this, we have that $E[X_t] = 1$, so we get $E[Re(X_t)]<\infty$ and $E[Im(X_t)]<\infty$ in a more direct way.

Finally, let $0\leq s<t$, then

$$E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s] = $$
$$= E[e^{iuN_t - \lambda t(e^{iu}-1)}|\mathcal{F}_s] = $$
$$= e^{- \lambda t(e^{iu}-1)}E[e^{iuN_t}|\mathcal{F}_s] =$$
$$= e^{- \lambda t(e^{iu}-1)}E[e^{iuN_t+iu(N_s-N_s)}|\mathcal{F}_s] =$$ 
$$= e^{- \lambda t(e^{iu}-1)}E[e^{iuN_t-iuN_s}e^{iuN_s}|\mathcal{F}_s] =$$
$$= e^{- \lambda t(e^{iu}-1)}e^{iuN_s}E[e^{iu(N_t-N_s)}|\mathcal{F}_s].$$

The last equality is valid because $e^{iuN_s}$ is $F_s$-measurable. The increments are stationary, so we have that $E[e^{iu(N_t-N_s)}|\mathcal{F}_s] = E[e^{iu(N_t-N_s)}] = e^{\lambda(t-s)(e^{iu}-1)}$. Therefore,
$$E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s] = $$
$$= e^{- \lambda t(e^{iu}-1)}e^{iuN_s}e^{\lambda(t-s)(e^{iu}-1)} = $$
$$= e^{- \lambda t(e^{iu}-1)+iuN_s+\lambda(t-s)(e^{iu}-1)} = $$
$$= e^{iuN_s-\lambda s(e^{iu}-1)} = X_s.$$

From this, we conclude that $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a $\mathcal{F}_t$-martingal. To prove that $(Re(X_t))_{t\geq 0}$ is also a $\mathcal{F}_t$-martingal, consider $0\leq s<t$, $A\in\mathcal{F}_s$ arbitrary and note that. 
$$E[X_t\cdot\textbf{I}_A] = E[X_s\cdot\textbf{I}_A] \implies \int_A X_t\ dP = \int_A X_s\ dP \implies$$
$$\implies \int_A Re(X_t)\ dP +i\int_A Im(X_t)\ dP = \int_A Re(X_s)\ dP +i\int_A Im(X_s)\ dP \implies$$ 
$$\int_A Re(X_t)\ dP =\int_A Re(X_s)\ dP $$ and
$$\int_A Im(X_t)\ dP =\int_A Im(X_s)\ dP. $$

Therefore, $E[Re(X_t)\cdot\textbf{I}_A]=E[Re(X_s)\cdot\textbf{I}_A]$ and $E[Im(X_t)\cdot\textbf{I}_A]=E[Im(X_s)\cdot\textbf{I}_A]$ for all $A\in\mathcal{F}_s$. This implies $E[Re(X_t)|\mathcal{F}_s] = Re(X_s)$ and $E[Im(X_t)|\mathcal{F}_s] = Im(X_s)$, and we are done.